# iOS debug build install fails

Tags: codenameone

I have a CN1 test project which was last built and successfully installed on various test devices in mid January 2017.

In rebuilding this project using the current CN1 version with the same certificate, provisioning profile and devices it now fails to install with the "Unable to Download App... could not be installed at this time." message.

Any suggestions as to what the issue might be?

I have also created a small test project using artifacts from a different Apple developer account with the same result.
I used the certificate wizard to create the certificate and provisioning profile for the test project.

TIA

Answer (score 4):

Check that the UDID of the device you are trying to install the app on is correct and attached to the app provisioning profile during the setup wizard.

Also, if the package name of your app changes, remove the existing app from your device before installing.

Lastly, Make sure your App doesn't have a similar reverse domain name as any app on the testing device...which includes your app's store build.

Comment: Don't forget this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/moving-to-64bit-by-default.html if you have a 32bit device you must add the build hint `ios.debug.archs=armv7`

Comment: Thanks Shai... that was the answer

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else caught out with old 32 bit devices you need to do this..

Don't forget this: codenameone.com/blog/moving-to-64bit-by-default.html if you have a 32bit device you must add the build hint ios.debug.archs=armv7 – Shai Almog 14 hours ago