# Codename one generated.ipa not installed on iPhone devices

Tags: codenameone

After successfully generated .ipa and trying to install in selected UDID devices, it's not being installed

It throws the error -- Unable to Download App "appname" could not be installed at this time.

We are trying install on iPhone 5s devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue may be related to this [ios-debug-build-install-fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237969/ios-debug-build-install-fails/42240824#42240824).

In addition to above, ensure that:

1. You are installing the app through itms:services by clicking **Install on device** on your iPhone 5s and click **install** on the new page.
2. you are installing the debug build and not the store build.
3. the UDID is accurate, copy N paste it instead of typing.
4. you are not behind any firewall that prevents downloading and your internet connection is good.

**Edit:**

Most developers experienced this due to testing on 32bit devices. Don't forget this [blog](http://codenameone.com/blog/moving-to-64bit-by-default.html).

If you are using any device older than iPhone 6, add the build hint `ios.debug.archs=armv7`.

Comment: We need to consider in build hint as per this link https://www.codenameone.com/blog/moving-to-64bit-by-default.html

Comment: Yes, I thought that might be the problem, but I didn't mention it since it's provided as a comment under my answer on that link. I edited my answer here to include that for whoever run into the same issue in future.

Comment: What's itms:services?