# iOS build does not work on registered iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, compatibility, codenameone

I went through the `iOS Certificate Wizard` with my iPhone plugged into my mac.
The phone settings says `Model ME508`, but the back of the phone says `Model A 1532`

The `Wizard` completed, then I built the `iOS` version and was installing it when it says `App not compatible with CPU`.

How do I get it to build for this phone? Better yet, how to I get it build for all iPhones and iPads?

[image]

Comment: Did you try the link that shows in the text behind that alert?  (A1532 should be a 5c with an armv7 cpu, not 64-bit.)

Comment: Yes, I did check that, but I could not find a definitive answer of 32 vs 64 bit for that model.  Looking at some of the sites that give iPhone specs, I can only assume 32 based on the tests they ran. So, thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 2):

5c is a 32 bit device. 32 bit will always work so enable that when in doubt, the reason it's not the default is because Apple has been "annoying" about it and shows a message that "this app might slow down your phone". Which is nonsense but very intimidating so it forces us to use the 64 bit version to avoid that message.

Comment: Try going over these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237969/ios-debug-build-install-fails